# How can i use Criteria class to have location? When i try to run the program. It crashes immediately. What is wrong with it?

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;//listten for location changes
    String provider;
    boolean gpsFix;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]
                        {
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                        }, 10);

                configureRequest();

            }
        }
        else
            configureRequest();
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                LatLng loc=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getAltitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(loc));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
    }

    private void configureRequest() {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    configureRequest();
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

When I change

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

to

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and remove

```
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

This statement program runs, but the purpose of me is to take locations as fast as I can. When I change it to network provider, location information comes very slow. How can I fix my criteria issue? Where am I doing wrong? Is there a way to take 100 location at a second?

Thank you..

Comment: Post the logcat for the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder whats the exact reason of getting too much location at a second ? (100 location)

Even aggressively usage of location providers never give what you want. If you wanna make an experience, try this below code (it will drain battery asap)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("NETWORK", 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("GPS", 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("PASSIVE", 0, 0, locationListener);
```

And last thing, i think it escaped your notice

```
LatLng loc=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getAltitude());
```

change to

```
LatLng loc=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

**Update**

First of all, notice that no way to get fresh location data as soon as possible (about 1 or 2 seconds). Also there are conditions you have to deal with like first fix, battery, accuracy. To getting satisfied location don't use under 5 seconds, so this is my opinion.

You could use fused location provider, it wraps gps and network providers under the hood, and gives you better location data. It simply does what you desire.

Otherwise, you can keep to improve below code

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("NETWORK", 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("GPS", 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("PASSIVE", 0, 0, locationListener);
```

It will use the providers aggressively too much and probably freeze app UI (even it works callback mechanism) So you could use other version of [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)) method.

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener, Looper looper)
```

Move your code in a new thread and pass it's looper too, then onLocationChanged method never occupy app main thread. So you can make every math operations on accuracy values of locations

Comment: The reason that i want to take 100 location is that the satellite sometimes dont give the right location. This cause 0-15 meters. To avoid that i want to take a lot of location in a second to take them average to reduce the location error.